# Convert an integer to a string of bytes

Tags: javascript, string, int

I've got a variable, let's call it `myNum`, containing a 32-bit value.  I'd like to turn it into a 4-byte string where each byte of the string corresponds to part of `myNum`.

I'm trying to do something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
var myNum = someFunctionReturningAnInteger();
var str = "";

str += String.charCodeFrom((myNum >>> 24) & 0xff);
str += String.charCodeFrom((myNum >>> 16) & 0xff);
str += String.charCodeFrom((myNum >>> 8) & 0xff);
str += String.charCodeFrom(myNum & 0xff);
```

For example, if `myNum` was equal to 350 then `str` would look like `0x00`,`0x00`,`0x01`,`0x5e` when I examine it in wireshark.

`charCodeFrom()` only does what I want when each individual byte has a value <= 0x7f .  Is there a browser-independent way to do what I'm trying to do?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: you can't.

In longer: this is happening because any character in a string with a value >= `0x80` will be encoded as unicode using the browser's default encoding (probably UTF-8, but occasionally you'll find a browser which pick something "random"). For example, if you send a "byte" with the value `\x80`, you'll likely see `\xC2\x80` on the wire (`"\xC2\x80".decode("utf-8") == u"\u0080").

You may be able to set the page encoding to an 8-bit encoding like CP1252, which *could* (in *some* browsers, when the stars correctly align) coax the browser into using that same encoding when it encodes JavaScript strings… But that's not going to be guaranteed cross-browser compatible.

Some more reliable options might be:

- Setup the end point to decode the strings coming from JS as unicode, then re-encode them as bytes (in Python, it would be something like `"".join(chr(ord(ub)) for ub in your_unicode_string)`)
- Send the "bytes" as an array of integers: `var bytes = [ (myNum >> 24) & 0xFF, … ];`

Comment: Excellent description of the issue.  However, once the string hits Javscript, it will be UTF16 so there is yet another layer of translation issues.

Comment: Thanks! And, yes, internally the "bytes" will be encoded with UTF16… But, apart from the fact that strings will take up twice as much memory as you'd expect, I can't think of any issues which would be caused by that specifically… Are there any?

Comment: Just noting that UTF8 and UTF16 encoding are different, so the octet sequences will be different.  I don't work with UTF16 often, but I am pretty sure that `x80` would be encoded as `\x00\x80` (UTF16) rather than `x\c2\x80` (UTF8)

Comment: Internally, yes, that's how it would be encoded… But over the wire the browser will encode it using (usually, in most cases) the page's encoding (so probably UTF-8).